# How can I create Marks in a Tkinter Text Widget's Vertical Scrollbar?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

Using a Text Widget in Tkinter, I want to highlight on the vertical scrollbar where the locations of found text are, similar to how Chrome highlights locations of words found in the Vertical Scrollbar if you use the Find option on a webpage. How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create Marks in a Tkinter Text Widget's Vertical Scrollbar?

You can't. The tkinter scrollbar doesn't support it. You will have to create your own scrollbar by drawing the various pieces on a canvas and then write code that mimics the scrollbar api.

Comment: Thank you. Writing something like that from scratch is a little beyond my current Python skills. Do you know of any sample code that mimics the scrollbar api that I could use as a basis to get started?